# Making a certain statement loop forever in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, infinite-loop

```
while 1 == 1:
    do = raw_input('What would you like to do?')
```

In the above example you can see that the code is meant to make something loop forever, for example:

```
if do == 'x':
    print 'y'
elif do == 'z':
    print 'a'
```

So this `if` statement has been carried out and I want the `raw_input` to be carried out again so that the person can enter something else and the program goes on again.

I would not like to put the entire program in a

```
while True:
```

program or a

```
while 1 != 2:
```

statement.

Comment: If your program only does that then why not wrap the whole thing in a `while 1==1` (aka a `while True`) loop?

Comment: This is just an example program.

Comment: If you want to make an infinite loop in Python the usual way is to use `while True:`. It's certainly cleaner than `while 1==1:` or while 1!=2:`, which are very ugly. If you want a clean-looking program without deeply nested code blocks then break your program up into functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do this until a certain condition is met, for example, the user types `q` to quit; otherwise it is just an infinite loop and you would need to force quit the entire program.

Try this logic instead:

```
result = raw_input('What would you like to do? Type q to quit: ')

while result.lower() != 'q':
    if result == 'x':
       print 'y'
    if result == 'z':
       print 'a'
    result = raw_input('What would you like to do? Type q to quit: ')
print('Quitting. Good bye!')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def user_input():

    do = raw_input('What would you like to do?')

    if do == 'x':
        print 'y'
        user_input()

    elif do == 'z':
        print 'a'
        user_input()

    elif do =='quit':
        print 'exiting user input'

    else:
        user_input()

user_input()
```

The above uses some recursive calls and is less succinct than a while statement, but would work if you are looking to avoid using while.

Comment: Yes, it does avoid the use of `while` but is that sufficient justification to use recursion? Remember that Python doesn't optimise tail-call recursion, and it has a recursion limit, so recursion in Python should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Appropriate for the name of this site, if nothing else